# Filtering an array result in a for each loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, filter

I have this code to create my array from file:

```
            <?php
            $servers = array();
            $handle = @fopen("data/data.txt", "r");

            if ($handle) {
                while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                    $line = explode("|", $buffer);
                    $servers[] = array(
                        "name" => $line[0],
                        "ip" => $line[1],
                        "type" => $line[2],
                    );
                }

                fclose($handle);
            }
            ?>
```

then i have this code to display the array:

```
                    <?php           
                foreach ($servers as $name => $servers): ?>
                            <td style="width:340px;">&nbsp;<?php echo $servers['name']; ?></td>
                            <td style="width:240px;"><?php echo $servers['ip']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is the array sample:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => aaa
        [ip] => 123
        [type] => good
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => bbb
        [ip] => 345
        [type] => good
    )
)
```

suppose i need to filter the result with array type is good,
im trying with this code but it only returns the last array:

```
                    <?php           
                foreach ($servers as $name => $servers): ?>
                    <?php if($servers['type']=="good"){?>
                            <td style="width:340px;">&nbsp;<?php echo $servers['name']; ?></td>
                            <td style="width:240px;"><?php echo $servers['ip']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the variable name in foreach loop (use $server instead of $serves as $servers already exists and contains your data)

```
 <?php foreach ($servers a $server): ?>
           <?php if($server['type']=="good"){?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:340px;">&nbsp;<?php echo $server['name']; ?></td>
                    <td style="width:240px;"><?php echo $server['ip']; ?></td>
                </tr>
           <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

## Edit 1

Filter the array, then print it

```
<?php
    //Filter the array
    $goodValues = array_filter($servers, function($e){
        return $e['type'] == "good";
        //Use this to be sure
        //return strtolower($e['type']) == "good";
    });

    //Print the values
    foreach ($goodValues as $value):  ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:340px;">&nbsp;<?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
            <td style="width:240px;"><?php echo $value['ip']; ?></td>
        </tr> 
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: would you post the full html table, i think you miss a tag `tr` or a `td`

Comment: if i removed the my filter code:           <?php if($server['type']=="good"){}?>
all the my arrays are displaying fine.. is their any other way to filter my arrays?

Comment: I added an alternative answer using `array_filter`

Answer (score 0):

As this is just numaric array and you're not using the key anywhere inside the body of the loop, you don't need to use `as $key => $value` and only `as $value` will suffice. Also notice the different variable names.

```
<?php foreach ($servers as $server): ?>
    <?php if($server['type']=="good"){?>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:340px;">&nbsp;<?php echo $server['name']; ?></td>
            <td style="width:240px;"><?php echo $server['ip']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i tried it but still same output.. returning only the last array